# How to find user input value in specific value when user enter any input value by himself

Tags: android

We have some specific values like 420, 5430, 7420 etc. How to find user input value in specific value when user enter any input value by himself in Edit text box?
2- If the user's input value is not found in our specified values, then how can we find the closest value from the specified values according to user input value?
For example, if the user types 430 and we have the closest value 420, we will display 420 as output to the user. My question is how can we use our code to find the closest value that is closest to the user's input value?

Comment: Can you share the code that you already have? Should users only enter numbers or any type of input?

Comment: Users only enter number as input. I have no code for this but do trying.

Comment: put your values in a dynamic int array and add the user Value to the array and put the content of this array to a new int[] and then use function Array.sort to arrange your array from small to large.

Comment: public static int findClosest(int[] arr, int n, int target) {
        int left = 0, right = n-1;
        while (left < right) {
            if (Math.abs(arr[left] - target) <= Math.abs(arr[right] - target)) {
                right--;
            } else {
                left++;
            }
        }
        return arr[left];
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9 };
        int n = arr.length;
        int target = 11;
        System.out.println(findClosest(arr, n, target));
    }